# DotnetZip zipar arquivo sem as pastas do diretório

Tags: c#, arquivo-zip

Estou usando o dotnetzip para zipar um arquivo porem o arquivo zip leva a raiz de diretório do arquivo, queria zipar apenas o arquivo sem os diretórios:

```
    public static void Zipar(FileInfo file)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.Password = "******";
            zip.AddFile(file.FullName);

            zip.Save(file.FullName.Replace(file.Extension,".zip"));
        }
    }
```

Dentro do arquivo zip fica assim: `\pasta\pasta\arquivo.txt`

Queria que ficasse assim: `arquivo.txt`

Comment: Estava tentando zipar com senha e não estava funcionando, até que percebi que ele só coloca senha se o arquivo não estiver vazio, no meu caso ele gerava o arquivo depois zipava mais pra testar, o programa n colocava os dados para economizar tempo nos testes, então acho interessante falar isso pra quem passar por algo assim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você informar um segundo parâmetro no método `AddFile` veja:

```
public static void Zipar(FileInfo file)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.Password = "******";
        zip.AddFile(file.FullName,""); //Aqui, se não informar o diretório ele vai ficar na raiz do arquivo

        zip.Save(file.FullName.Replace(file.Extension,".zip"));
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado funcionou.