# Compactar um arquivo salvo em Banco

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo-zip

boa tarde!
tenho um arquivo que esta salvo em banco, e preciso zipar esse arquivo, qndo for baixa-lo.
Como que faço?
muitíssimo obrigado pelo apoio

Comment: já tens o código de salvar o arquivo em disco ? depois basta usar o DotNet.ZIP: exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253856/69359

Comment: não, vou da uma olhada nesse link.
Não é possivel zipar o que ver direto do banco?

Comment: direto do banco vem um array de bytes, stream, ... não sei se dá certo fazer isso

Comment: entendi... como faço para salvar do banco em disco. 
Infelizmente não tenho com usar essa biblioteca recomendada

Comment: Qual é a versão do .NET Framework que você tá usando, @RicardoSoares?

Comment: é a 4.0 e infelizmente não da suporte ZipArchive

Comment: Com essa restrição acho que usei uma vez a biblioteca DotNetZip, deve ter no nuget

Comment: vou tentar com o Ionic. Infelizmente não posso add outros componentes...

Comment: Mas essa lib é compativel com Ionic
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ionic.Zip/

Answer (score 0):

[A partir do .NET Framework 4.5 Beta](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/05/21/net-framework-gets-zip.aspx), é possível manipular arquivos ZIP. Exemplo baseado [neste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.compression.ziparchivemode(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"c:\users\exampleuser\Desktop\release.zip", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
                {
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"c:\users\exampleuser\Desktop\MeuArquivoACompactar.dat", "arquivo.dat");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: opa...obrigado pela ajuda. mas fiz pelo ionic, por conta da versão do .net